# How to disable clipboard on Samsung's keyboard?

Tags: javascript, react-native, samsung-mobile

Is there any workaround to disable the clipboard on the Samsung's keyboard.

I have already removing the clipboard data `TextField` events

```
const handleFocus = (e: NativeSyntheticEvent<TextInputFocusEventData>) => {
  ...
    Clipboard.setString(''); // clear any text copied from text field
  ...
};

const handleBlur = (e: NativeSyntheticEvent<TextInputFocusEventData>) => {
  ...
    Clipboard.setString(''); // clear any text copied from text field
  ...
};

const handleOnSelectionChange = () => {
  ...
    Clipboard.setString(''); // clear any text copied from text field
  ...
};
```

I have also have

```
pointerEvents: 'none',
removeClippedSubviews: true,
```

But there's history of clipboard on Samsung keyboard. How to get rid of this?

Thank you.